# Set textfield in UISearchBar

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to add SearchController to UINavigationBar. I'm trying to set UITextField of UISearchBar after back button of UINavigationController. I want some more space after back button

[image]

When I start searching it appears as

[image]

Whereas I should be able to view back button. Only textfield width should be decreased. Also after Cancel it should be again back to initial layout. Whereas it is displayed as below:

[image]

Below is my code

```
var searchResultController = UISearchController()
    
self.searchResultController = ({
        
    let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        
    controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(controller.searchBar)
        
    return controller
})()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    for subView in searchResultController.searchBar.subviews{
        for subsubView in subView.subviews  {
            if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField {
                var bounds: CGRect
                bounds = textField.frame
                bounds.size.width = self.view.bounds.width - 50    
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please let me know how can I fix this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For setting the UIsearchBar add it to Navigation's titleView as

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = controller.searchBar
```

For removing Cancel button we can use UISearchControllerDelegate method

```
func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
}
```

Hope this may help any one.